# Want to get the value from the string which in dictionary format

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Want to get the value from the **string** at the **dictionary** which in **json** format, in this example selected **key** as **pp-0** and expected output = **'1000'**

**Python Coding**

```
x = {'d': 'AAAAA@##{"pp-0": "1000", "pp-1": "1001", "pp-2": "1002", "pp-3": "1003", "pp-4": "1004", "pp-5": "1005", "pp-6": "1006", "pp-7": "1007", "pp-8": "1008", "pp-9": "1009", "pp-10": "1010", "pp-11": "1011", "pp-12": "1012", "pp-13": "1013", "pp-14": "1014", "pp-17": "1015", "pp-27": "1016"}'}
x['d'].get('pp-0')
```

**Error Message**

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**Expected Result**

```
'1000'
```

Comment: `json.loads` Can convert a JSON string into a dictionary, but the string is not in JSON format. There is invalid data at the start of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this. Access the `d` key first and strip the `AAAAA@##`. This will result in valid JSON and can be deserialize to python objects via `json` module.

```
>>> tmp = x['d'].removeprefix("AAAAA@##")
>>> # `removeprefix` method added in python 3.9. If you are using python version 
>>> # less than 3.9 you can slice the string instead `x['d'][8:]``
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(tmp).get('pp-0')
'1000'
```

Comment: dear, what is the difficult between strip and removeprefix ? it seem almost the same

Comment: When you use `strip` [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)(for eg: `'www.example.com'.strip('cmowz.')`), the argument(`cmowz.` in this case) is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped(result would be `'example.com'`). But in the case of `removeprefix(prefix)` it will remove `prefix` only  If the string starts with the `prefix`

Answer (score 1):

If the prefix of the `json`ified string is unknown, `re.sub` can be used:

```
import json, re
x = {'d': 'AAAAA@##{"pp-0": "1000", "pp-1": "1001", "pp-2": "1002", "pp-3": "1003", "pp-4": "1004", "pp-5": "1005", "pp-6": "1006", "pp-7": "1007", "pp-8": "1008", "pp-9": "1009", "pp-10": "1010", "pp-11": "1011", "pp-12": "1012", "pp-13": "1013", "pp-14": "1014", "pp-17": "1015", "pp-27": "1016"}'}
r = {a:json.loads(re.sub('^[^\{]+', '', b)) for a, b in x.items()}
print(r['d'].get('pp-0'))
```

Output:

```
1000
```